# How to pass array values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, postman

How we can pass array like below in postman
and how can we get this array in node JavaScript using express?

Following array to be passed in postman:

```
data : [
            {
                name: 'ABC',
                amount: '1500',                     
            },
            {
                name: 'NNS',
                amount: '5800',                     
            },
            {
                name: 'GED',
                amount: '3500',                     
            },
            {
                name: 'PQR',
                amount: '5500',                     
            }
        ]
```

**Edit :**
// in app.js

```
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
      extended: true
    }));
```

[image]

//users.js  { router }

```
router.post('/test', function(req, res, next){

  console.log(req.body.data);
  res.send(req.body.data);
});
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send your array with the Postman by following the steps below:

[image]

your json must be like this:

```
    {
    "data" : [
                {   "name": "ABC",
                    "amount": 1500                    
                },
                {   "name": "NNS",
                    "amount": 5800                    
                },
                {   "name": "GED",
                    "amount": 3500                    
                },
                {   "name": "PQ",
                    "amount": 5500                    
                }
        ]
    }
```

and you can retrieve this POST query in node (express) like this:

```
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
      extended: true
    })); 

    app.post('/people', function(req, res, next) {
      //show received data
       console.log(req.body.data);
    });
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but somewhere stucking.. I update my question with picture. please revert if you can.

Comment: @iam correct your json, it should be like the one mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

send in data parameters

```
key     => value
data[]  =>  {"name": "ABC", "amount": "1500"}
data[]  =>  {"name": "ABC", "amount": "1500"}
data[]  =>  {"name": "ABC", "amount": "1500"}
```

but i think this will convert the value to string ["{name:value}",...]